# Django: allauth facebook

Tags: django, facebook, django-socialauth, django-allauth

I have a login button in my site, which opens facebook login in new window, ask user to login fetch neccesary informations and immediately logout that user and close that temporary window. Problems comes when next user again click login button new window open and it doesn't ask for login informations it by default assumes that previous user has already logged in...How do I override these facebook logins for different users?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has support for re-authentication: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/client-side-re-auth/

This forces the user to re-enter his password. However, at this point the user cannot decide to login as a different user.

Support for re-authentication has just been added to the master development branch of `django-allauth`:

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/commit/8a8f9902b4c7a1f5d079d1422be2976b51e5b7b9

If you prefer to use 0.9.0 (which does not contain support for this yet) you can easily override the "facebook/fbconnect.html" template and pass along the `auth_type` parameter to the `FB.login` API call yourself.

Comment: thanks for that.....I have another doubt is how can I make user like a page as he logs in automatically...